# How to skip the 50 records and after that find the matched records in mongodb by using findOne query in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
dbo.collection('Gps').findOne({$skip: 50}, {  captureDateTime :a5},function (err, result) {
                        if (result) {
                            dbo.collection("OBD").insertOne({ sensortype: 'OBD', captureDateTime: result.captureDateTime, vehiculeData: b5 }, function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                else
                                    console.log('OBD matched with GPS');
                            })
                        }
                    });
```

Its not getting proper result. I want to skip the 50 records and then from remaining records I want matched records based on capturedatetime and push it in OBD collection.

I also tried for

```
  dbo.collection('Gps').aggregate([ 
                       {$skip : 50},
                        { $match : { captureDateTime : a5 } } 
                    ]).toArray( function (err, result) {
                        if (result) {
                            dbo.collection("OBD").insertOne({ sensortype: 'OBD', captureDateTime: result.captureDateTime, vehiculeData: b5 }, function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                else
                                    console.log('OBD matched with GPS');
                            })
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be this can solve your problem link: https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-skip-limit.php

```
dbo.collection('Gps').findOne().skip(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

`findOne()` does not support `skip()`, since a document is retrieved rather than a cursor. You might use the following method instead :

```
db.getCollection('Gps').find({captureDateTime :"a5"}).skip(50).limit(1)
```